# How would you simply Monitor.TryEnter

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, parallel-processing

I'm trying to make things simpler. Here is my code:

```
    If Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(syncRoot) Then
        Try
            'do something
        Finally
            Threading.Monitor.Exit(syncRoot)
        End Try
    Else
        'do something else
    End If
```

This is even worse than the ReaderWriterLock in terms of noise.
I can use C# or VB, so answers applying to either will be welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a delegate?

E.g.

```
public bool TryEnter(object lockObject, Action work) 
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject)) 
    {
       try 
       {
          work();
       }
       finally 
       {
           Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
       }        
       return true;
     }

     return false;
}
```

Comment: Totally useless for VB (no anonymous Action delegates), but I can see it working with C#.

Can you show how you foresee it being called?

Comment: Simplest would be with a lambda: TryEnter(obj, ()=>{...code...})), where the return tells you whether it was done or not.

Comment: Now that VB 10 has anonymous delegates, this is my favorite solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is very similar to your [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170028/how-would-you-simplfy-entering-and-exiting-a-readerwriterlock), and I would expect a similar answer. The only significant difference is that you might return "null" from your method if the timeout fails - then the "Dispose()" is not called, and you can easily check the value:

```
using(var token = GetLock(syncLock, timeout)) {
  if(token != null) { ... }
}
```

The only real glitch is that you don't necessarily want to add an extension method to "object" (or even "T where T : class")...

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has looked at this in the past - [worth a look](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/locking.html).

Comment: Passing a possible null to the using block is a neat trick. But it still feels kludgey to me.