# Does calling Clear disposes the items also?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, dispose

Many times there is a clear method, that removes all the items from the collections, are these items disposed also.

Like,

```
toolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Clear();
```

is sufficient, or should I have to call like that:

```
foreach (ToolStripItem item in toolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems)
{
  toolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Remove(item);
  item.Dispose();
}
```

Edit: Well ToolStripItem is an example not a question, for those who says Clear is enough I found another example, TabControl has also item collection and clear method. But TabControls can have complex controls (at least I have), which needs to be explicitly Dispose (even if they are Disposed automatically at some point by GC, cause they take huge memory). I guess the best answer is divo comment to dispose the items, and then call clear.

Comment: I believe the author is a C/C++ developer that "needs" to dispose the resources in every function, even if in .NET is not a such necessity. I doubt about the necessity of Finalize/Dispose items after *Clear* ing it from the collection.

Comment: @serhio - in .NET, it is still your job to call `Dispose()` on `IDisposable` resources, or ensure that `Dispose()` is called by some other code.

Comment: Using .NET Reflector is a good way to see whether `ToolStripItemCollection.Clear()` actually calls `Dispose` on the collection items or not. If you look at the disassembled source you will see that it doesn't.

Comment: @Marc: tell me one cause why should I dispose a ToolStripItem? I'd simply leaved this task to the GC.

Comment: @divo: You may only suppose. I don't know, but IMHO I don't think the author wrote its custom ToolStripItem that uses unmanaged resources.

Comment: @divo, somehow `var item` won't work, you need `IDisposable` for calling `Dispose`.

Comment: @Prinyank: Could you explain if you use custom ToolStripItems, and why you need the Dispose method on them? Apparently you have found the answer of your "Does calling Clear disposes the items also?"

Comment: @serhio: Whether or not a `ToolStripItem` actually uses unmanaged resources or not is an **implementation detail**.  The fact is, it implements `IDisposable`, and the **contract** of `IDisposable` says "This object MAY directly or indirectly use some unmanaged resources, and you should dispose of it whenever you are done with it."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Q: *Does?*

A: *No* - `Clear` does not dispose the items (they could be used in other parts of your application).

So, if your ToolStripItems are standard .NET ones, should `Clear` be sufficient? After some reflection I'd say "probably not".

Yeah, this is true that if you will have any references to the ToolStripItem in other part of your application, the .NET **GarbageCollector** will destroy(use the class *destructor*) it automatically. But, it **will not call the *`Dispose(true)`* method**, that is, however, required for the form's `IDisposable` components.

Read a propos [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2004/02/20/77435.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691846/does-garbage-collector-call-dispose).

Actually, I believe that you will, however, need to explicitly `Dispose` your Items, like the ToolStrip's *Dispose* method does (replace *this* by *yourToolStrip*):

```
if (!this.Items.IsReadOnly)
{
    for (int i = this.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        this.Items[i].Dispose();
    }
    this.Items.Clear();
}
```

## EDIT

I also created [the following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969705/clear-controls-does-not-dispose-them-what-is-the-risk) to clarify this question more generally.

Comment: No, clear won't be sufficient if the objects in the collection need disposal. The finalizer *might* dispose the object; however, it is not deterministic when this will occur and it is not certain that it will occur at all (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx: "The Finalize method might not run to completion or might not run at all in the following exceptional circumstances..."

Comment: I doubt about the necessity of Finalize/Dispose items after *Clear* ing it from the collection.

Comment: Hi serhio, shouldn't this 'If you will have any references' should be 'If you do not have any references'

Comment: @Priyank: No, **when** (nobody knows exactly) GC *will* collect the garbage, it *will* verify the references. This is why I used the future.

Comment: I guess its still confusing, if you have any references in other part of your application, why would GarbageCollector will destroy(Dispose) it automatically? As you still got references. I am sorry, but this sentence makes me confuse.

Comment: @Priyank: Normally, the GC destroys the non-used(referenced) anymore objects. However, all the .NET code Dispose explicitly, like other people mentioned, components in a Form. You will need in this case (of dynamical addition) dispose it by yourself before Clear -ing the parent Container(ToolStrip).

Comment: Two corrections to your last edit: 1. In .NET objects don't have a destructor, they have a `Finalize` method which *might* eventually be called by the garbage collector. This is quite different from the destructor known from C++ 2. The `Finalize` method of `ToolStripItem` actually *does* call `Dispose(false)` as recommended when implementing the dispose pattern.

Comment: @divo: .NET objects **does have a destructor ~()** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b%28VS.80%29.aspx that use implicitly Finalize. When overriding a destructor, you even could remove the Finalize method(even if this does not make sense)

Comment: @serhio That's quite a tricky one. Destructors in .NET are NOT immediately called on the objects when it is not used anymore. It is up to the `GarbageCollector` to decide when to call them. Yes, they are eventually all called, but it is NOT deterministic. You cant rely on them. However, if you don't want to call `Dispose()` on every object in the `ListView` and you don't care about *when* the object is really destroyed, then you could override the `Destructor` and wait for `GC` to call it on these objects.

Answer (score 2):

You should rely on `Dispose()` call when you're dealing with unmanaged memory, shared resources or large memory areas. Doesn't seems this case.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `Clear` doesn't dispose the items, but it removes the reference from the collection to the items. If that was the only reference to the items they will be garbage collected automatically at some point (which you can't predict, but you may control using the `GC` class).

Comment: Relying on the garbage collector for disposal is not safe. See my comment on serhio's answer.

Comment: @divo: there is any necessity to fill your code with garbage if your ToolStripItem is a standard WinForm object.

Comment: @serhio: In a "normal" Windows Forms application it is usually not necessary to call `Component.Dispose()` explicitly as it is already called then the form is closed (See the designer-generated code behind, it overwrites `Dispose` and calls `Dispose` on each component used in the form). However, if you add and remove components dynamically at runtime, it is your responsibility to explicitly dispose these components.

Comment: I never implied that you need to rely on garbage collection for disposing. I merely answered the question.

Comment: @Aviad: My comment was just a nitpick that "at some point" can also mean *never*. IMHO that makes an important difference.

Comment: Correct programming is always to explicitly call `Dispose` (or use `using`) on disposable objects.

Comment: @divo: Dispose is use on the Form's **Components**. The ToolStripMenu Items are form's **Controls** and they does not need an explicitly dispose.

Comment: @serhio: And a `Control` *is* a `Component`: `public class Control : Component, IDropTarget, ISynchronizeInvoke, IWin32Window, IBindableComponent, IComponent, IDisposable`

Comment: @divo, yes, but you told about the designer's code, that overrides the Dispose and calls it on every component in form's components collection. The toolstripItems are never added in this private (components) collection by the designer, so designer never disposes them.

Comment: @serhio: I suggest you to dive into the .NET sources using Reflector. You will see that `Form` derives from `Control` which calls `Dispose` on all of its child components in its own `Dispose` method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so,more, it can cause many logical problems because you may have reference to that object in the collection for later use. If you don't have references to that objects Garbage Collector will dispose that objects later