# Huge memory usage in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have some problems running my app on some old `Android`devices, and I therefore downloaded a trail of Visual Studio Professionel, as it has `Diagnostics Tools`.

I tried doing some simple stuff in my app, and I find it is scaring, that `Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty+BindablePropertyContext` takes a size (in bytes of course) of `2.196.088` in UWP, which you can see at the following screendump.

[image: UWP Managed memory].

In the example I have justed navigated through 5 pages. On 2 of the pages there are `ListViews`, and one of them have been cleared 3 times, and filled with new data.

So do I have to call `GC.Collect()` after clearing the `ListView`?

Comment: Calling `GC.Collect()` is never recommended as it may break other stuff in your code. `Clear()` for `ListView` does NOT call `Dispose()` on your objects which means `GC` has to take time to make sure those objects are not referenced anywhere else before collecting them. If you want, you could go in a loop and `Dispose()` each item in the `ListView` which will ensure you destroy them. Take a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969024/does-calling-clear-disposes-the-items-also

Comment: @Everyone `GC.Collect()` never breaks any other stuff, it just makes app slow as it is CPU intensive job.

Comment: @AkashKava True, sorry. It consumes the performance, wouldn't break running code, but would drastically slow it down.. like A LOT

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue - navigating through pages a couple of times caused an OutOfMemoryException. For me the solution was to implement custom render for page with explicit Dispose() call.

```
public class CustomPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    private NavigationPage _navigationPage;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        _navigationPage = GetNavigationPage(Element);
        SubscribeToPopped(_navigationPage);
    }

    private void SubscribeToPopped(NavigationPage navigationPage)
    {
        if (navigationPage == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        navigationPage.Popped += OnPagePopped;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Log.Info("===========Dispose called===========");
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void OnPagePopped(object sender, NavigationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Page != Element)
        {
            return;
        }

        Dispose(true);
        _navigationPage.Popped -= OnPagePopped;
    }

    private static NavigationPage GetNavigationPage(Element element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (element.Parent == null || element.Parent.GetType() == typeof(NavigationPage))
            {
                return element.Parent as NavigationPage;
            }

            element = element.Parent;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530253/memory-leak-handling-xamarin-forms) but you need to be careful with disposing images, it may cause some problems if their parent page is in navigation stack and you want to go back.

Comment: Thanks @maddhew. I have just converted 90-95% of the events to Commands, which I hope will help. The other 5-10% did I move from the constructor to OnAppearing and unassigning in OnDisappearing. 
And I have converted all images to 9-patches (on Android).
I hope it will take some of it.