# how to close active SQL Server connections?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using following code in dispose() method

```
 Public Sub Dispose() Implements System.IDisposable.Dispose
            If Not IsDBNull(Command) And Not Command Is Nothing Then
                Dim tmpsqlcon As SqlConnection
                tmpsqlcon = Command.Connection
                Debug.Assert(Not IsDBNull(tmpsqlcon))
                SqlConnection.ClearPool(tmpsqlcon)
                tmpsqlcon.Close()
                Command.Dispose()
                tmpsqlcon.Dispose()
            End If
        End Sub
```

and calling this method everytime in the database operation. But it still show me too many active connection.

Comment: how do you use command and connection in code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use dispose if you connect to your db with using statement:

**Example:**

```
Dim queryString As String = _
    "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;" 

Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
    connection.Open()

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

    ' Call Read before accessing data. 
    While reader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", _
            reader(0), reader(1)))
    End While 

    ' Call Close when done reading.
    reader.Close()
End Using
```

this is the way you should connect to your db.

some more info:

[how to close a sqlconnection in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850382/how-to-close-a-sqlconnection-in-asp-net)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2