# When is it necessary to dispose db connection

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a class that contains several common methods customized for use in my MVC app, that I use in several places.  Here is an example of some:

```
    private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();


    public List<SelectListItem> GetLocationList()
    {
        var query =
                db.v_LocationsAlphabetical.OrderByDescending(x => x.Category).ThenBy(x => x.LocationName).ToList()
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.LocationID.ToString(),
                    Text = x.LocationName
                });

        return (query).ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStates()
    {
        var query = db.States.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Abbr,
            Text = x.Name
        });

        return(query);
    }

    public List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        var query = db.Person.OrderBy(m => m.LastName).ThenBy(m => m.FirstName).ToList();

        return (query);

    }
```

Each one of these methods makes a call to the database to get data and I was wondering if I need to add a dispose to each method.  If not, why?  Thanks.

Comment: Completely unrelated but is there a reason why you always return your query between parethesis?

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't call dispose in each method, because the lifetime of `db` is the same as that of the enclosing class since it's not a local variable in a method.

The typical way to handle this is to make the current class `IDisposable` and call `db.Dispose()` in the `Dispose()` method.

Comment: And this would be usually incorrect. Calling Dispose on a DbContext is usually not needed as there is nothing to dispose.  This comes directly from the EF team who wrote the DbConext class.  For a full explanation of why http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html#.Ua0IS5yXT0U

Comment: @RobertMcKee: It seems an interesting choice to mark a class as `IDisposable` when it should not be disposed.

Comment: It is only required if you are manually manipulating the connection yourself.  Otherwise there will be nothing to dispose.  Since most people don't manually open and close the connection themselves, the disposal is optional.

Comment: Interesting blog post.  I never knew that.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.  One thing I should point out, I'm pretty sure I am not using dbContext objects, rather I think they are ObjectContext (I am still pretty new to all this).  I am using Db First, so I create an edmx file from the existing db then create an instance with: private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();.  Does this impact y'alls answers?

Answer (score 0):

No.  DbContexts don't have to be manually disposed, unless you manually manage the connection yourself.  Therefore, disposing them is usually optional.

Comment: Garbage collection happens automatically based on scope accessibility, but disposal does not.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691846/does-garbage-collector-call-dispose

Comment: Response from the EF team (The ones who wrote the DbContext class) explaining why in almost all cases, DbContexts don't need to be manually disposed: http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html#.Ua0IS5yXT0U

Comment: You edited your answer.  Previously, it was incorrect. I've given you an upvote.

Comment: The answer was correct, but the why was technically wrong.  I've edited it so that it is correct, and mentioned the unusual circumstances in which you have to manually dispose the DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of handling db connection in .NET 
One of my favorites is the one called `one dbcontext per request`, which basically means you initialize your dbcontext when needed, do the work without thinking about instantiating or disposing, and dispose automatically when the request is done. (kinda UnitOfWork-ish)

I've already shown this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10153406/1289283). It's not only applicable to EF, but to Linq2SQL, ADO.NET, etc. as well.