# Detect AVPlayerItem Status change

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

This is my (Xamarin C#) code: (`player` is an `AVPlayer`.)

```
var v = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("Status"), ReadyNow, player.CurrentItem);
```

It never calls `ReadyNow(NSNotification obj)` even though the player plays fine.

How do I fix it to call the method? (I don't know if the error is in the Xamarin/C# part or in the object I'm using etc. which would be the same error if written in Swift.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the player's current item and add the observer to it.

The property:

```cs
private AVPlayerItem CurrentItem => Player.CurrentItem;
```

The observer:

```cs
CurrentItem.AddObserver(this, new NSString("status"), 
    NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial,
    StatusObservationContext.Handle);
```

If you want, you can also attach [loadedTimeRanges](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1389953-loadedtimeranges):

```cs
CurrentItem.AddObserver(this, new NSString("loadedTimeRanges"), 
    NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New,
    LoadedTimeRangesObservationContext.Handle);
```

NB: Always be sure to detach the observer for the status before attaching:

```cs
CurrentItem.RemoveObserver(this, new NSString("status"));
```

Edit: `StatusObservationContext` is simply a property, pointing to `status` string.

```cs
public static readonly NSString StatusObservationContext = new NSString("Status");
```

*Useful resources*
You can find everything that you may need for your `AVPlayer` implementation in Martinj's excellent package - `XamarinMediaManager`.

Sources:

1. [Play Audio and Video with the MediaManager Plugin for Xamarin](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/play-audio-and-video-with-the-mediamanager-plugin-for-xamarin/)
2. [Plugin.MediaManager NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.MediaManager/)
3. [GitHub](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager)

Comment: Thanks. `Always be sure to detach the observer for the status to an item without one!` - I don't understand that sentence.

Comment: Also, I don't have a `StatusObservationContext`.

Comment: I used it a little different, but the `CurrentItem.AddObserver` is what led me on the right path. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I upvoted your answer too (and the other answer as well) but it looks like someone downvoted both. They are both now at 0 but the breakdown shows a +1 (mine) and a -1 for both answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to observe on the single `AVPlayerItem` instance is currently held in the `CurrentItem` property, even if it is currently null.

You can observe on the `AVPlayer` instance and use the `keyPath` of the `NSObject` that you wish to observe changes on:

#### Example:

```
obs = player.AddObserver("currentItem", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, (NSObservedChange obj) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{obj.NewValue}");
});
```

Note: Hold a ref. to the returned `IDisposable` otherwise your observer can go out of scope and|or you will leak mem.

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking that out now. But what did you mean by that last paragraph? Are you referring to `obs`? I thought I can just ignore it and let it get GCd. If not - I'm really glad I asked this question!

Comment: @ispiro The observable `IDisposable` is holding a naive ref, GC'ing does not call dispose:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691846/does-garbage-collector-call-dispose